# Move Product Attribiutes from More information Tab to details tab

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-page

I would like to move all product attributes from selected product to details tab.

I try to do something like this:

`<move element="product.attribute" destination="content" after="-">`
But this solution is not good form me because i would like to display product attribute only in Details tab not in all around product page.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can try for this .  where #additional is id of more information tab and #description is id of Details tab.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

        var additional_information = jQuery('#additional').clone();
        jQuery('#additional').remove();
        jQuery('#description').append(additional_information);
        jQuery('#additional').show();

    })
});
```

*This Script Only used For details page*